# Transformation of an unconstrained binary quadratic optimization problem into a constrained binary linear programming problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, global-optimization

I know that a constrained linear optimization problem can be transformed into an unconstrained binary quadratic optimization problem (UBQP). Does anyone know if the inverse result is solved in the literature? Is there a procedure to transform a UBQP problem into a constrained binary linear programming problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the linearization of a product of binary variables is well known:
https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables